# React redirecting to wrong file after deployment in vercel, working fine in local

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to JavaScript. I have created a React project. When a user click on "about button" it should show 'about.html' ( which was present in root folder ) to user. This was working fine in local development. But when i deployed this project in vercel. It was showing index.html file. This is my project structure. Any solution for this problem will be highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the ***`about.html`*** file to the ***`public`*** folder. And update your ***`Link`*** element's ***`href`*** with ***`/about.html`***